# Jquery after ajax call script doesn't work anymore

Tags: jquery, ajax

i'm developing a php page that manage the access to some pubs....
right now i'm stuck with one hell of problem.

let me explain....

i have a button that call an ajaxrequest and reload a specific div called #entry 
the problem arise when i try to access ther property of #entry AFTER the ajax request.

HTML STRUCTURE

```
<div id="all">
    <div id="prenotazioni" class="mobile-left">
        <? CController::renderpartial('_lista'); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="entry" class="mobile-right" style="width:280px;position:absolute;bottom:0px;right:0px;">
        <? CController::renderpartial('_pren'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the jquery code that have problem is the follow

```
       $(window).scroll(function() {
                $("#all").parent("div").find("#entry").css("bottom","");
                $("#all").parent("div").find("#entry").css("top", $(window).height() - $("#entry").outerHeight() + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");        
         });
```

so until i call the ajax everithing works fine after that nothing...... somebody can help me?????

Thanks

EDITED

```
jQuery('body').undelegate('#yt0','click').delegate('#yt0','click',function(){jQu‌​ery.ajax({'type':'GET','data':{'id_lista':-1},'url':'/mobile/showlista','cache':false,'success':function(html){jQuery("#all"‌​).html(html)}});return false;});
```

_PREN

```
<div id="tipo"></div>
<input name="report[id_pren]" id="report_id_pren" type="hidden" value=""/>
<div id="ingresso">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="margin-right: 10px;">
            <div class="male" >
                <span id="male_nr" class="nr">0</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="female">
                <span id="female_nr" class="nr">0</span>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="line-height: 53px;">INGRESSI
            <div id="totale_div" style="float:right;">
                <span id="totale">0</span>
            </div>

            </td>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2" style="text-align:right;"><input type="image" src="../images/mobile/invio.gif" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="line-height: 53px;">
           OMAGGI
            <div id="omaggi_div" style="float:right;">
               <span id="omaggi"> 0</span>
            </div>

        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:50px;">
            <input type="button" id="omgplus" class="omgplus" />
            <input type="button"id="omgminus"  class="omgminus" />
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>  
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your AJAX call with fallbacks too.

Comment: Is it possible that after ajax call html structure changed?

Comment: tell us how you load the ajax and how you insert the results from it in the DOM

Comment: I think you need to post the rendered HTML you get and how you are making the AJAX call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing the contents of the `#all` element with the returned results from the Ajax call. So both `#prenotazioni` and `#entry` get removed from the DOM.

Perhaps you need to put the ajax results inside the `#prenotazioni` element. If so use

```
jQuery("#prenotazioni"‌​).html(html)}
```

---

General note

```
$("#all").parent("div").find("#entry").css(..)
```

should be

```
$("#all").find("#entry").css(..)
```

because `#all` is a container of `#entry` so you do not need to go further up the DOM hierarchy..

Comment: sadly i can't do that.... i need update both the div... and after that i need to access at the css property.

Comment: @Sakuya84, but the returned code (*if _PREN is that*) does not contain a `#entry` element..